# How to update a an item in a row of a database by selecting an item in a combo box

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi I am trying to update the quantity of an item in a row by selecting the item you want to increase the quantity of in a combo box. I also want it to add the quantity of the item in the database to the number that they are adding in. I'm guessing it will need an update statement but like I said I need to be able to add the number they are trying to put in to the number already in the database.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=food_pantry; uid=root; pwd=; ");
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        string insert = "INSERT INTO canned_goods(canned_goods.item, canned_goods.quantity) VALUES (@item, @quantity)";
        string update = "UPDATE SELECTED";
        string sql;

private void fillDataComboBox(string sql, ComboBox lst)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                dt = new DataTable();

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);

                lst.DataSource = dt;
                lst.DisplayMember = "item";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                da.Dispose();
            }

        }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sql = "SELECT item FROM `canned_goods`";
            fillItemListBox(sql, listBoxItem);
            fillQuantityListBox(sql, listBoxQuantity);
            fillDataComboBox(sql, comboBox1);
        }

private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(insert, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxItem.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = numericUpDown1.Value;
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted SuccessFully");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Failed To Insert SuccessFully");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + err);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

I have researched somethings to try and find some answers but nothing would work how I need it to.

Comment: *"I'm guessing it will need an update statement"* - If you want to update the value in an existing row in the table then yes.  Have you tried anything yet?  Have you looked up the syntax for an `UPDATE` statement in MySQL and made an attempt?  What didn't work as expected in that attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you want to sum up value from **numericUpDown** with value stored in db, to do this you can make request to obtain specific quantity

```
string sql = "SELECT quantity FROM `canned_goods` WHERE item = @item";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxItem.Text;
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int itemQuantity = 0;
if(reader.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    itemQuantity = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Then sum up it with value from **numericUpDown**.
Instead of your **string insert** use

```
UPDATE `canned_goods` SET quantity = @quantity WHERE item = @item
```

But pay attention SQL commands above will work correctly only if your column item contains unique values, otherwise
you sould use some unique **ID** value to work with.

Comment: Hi there I like your answer and I think it can be helpful but where would I put it. Would it be in the section just for the button or would it be in the combo box section. Thank you again.

Comment: I would put it in the begginig of **buttonSubmit_Click** handler, because in that case you don't have to change program and can get quantity you need. You can as well try to get all data in **Form_Load**, but in this case **ComboBox** wont fit to store all data, and i suggest to use **DataGridView** instead, and then get guantity you need from it.